# Why can't I enter Backend and Install.php after Upgrade to 11?

Tags: typo3, upgrade, typo3-11.x

After update from TYPO3 10.4.32 to 11.5. I can't login to backend (After entering login data I get the error `The requested URL was not found on this server.`).
`typo3/install.php` shows an ever rotating icon "Initalizing". It's an composer installation with helhum/typo3-secure-web.
Frontend is working....
Thanks for any help!

I've got two typo311 composer-installations with helhum/typo3-secure-web and same htaccess. One works, the other doesn't...

Frontend works, install.php is not accessible cause of initializing problem like above. Backend shows the navigation on the left side, but not pagetree and content. The backend links are like that:

https://works.de/typo3/module/**web/layout**

https://works.de/typo3/module/**web/list**

https://error.de/typo3/main?token=f9fc9325b02d5450ba04389fb3ba0d74e4f05939&redirect=**web_layout**

https://error.de/typo3/main?token=f9fc9325b02d5450ba04389fb3ba0d74e4f05939&redirect=**web_list**

Other upgrades to 11 without composer and helhum-file configuration private/public work as supposed.

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to Composer?

Comment: Did you update the .htaccess file? There were some changes for v11.

Answer (score 2):

```
# If the file/symlink/directory does not exist but is below /typo3/, redirect to the TYPO3 Backend entry point.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^typo3/(.*)$ %{ENV:CWD}typo3/index.php [QSA,L]
```

See https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/11.0/Breaking-93048-BackendURLRewrites.html for more info.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Hi, I've copied the root-htaccess from the FolderStructureTemplateFiles, now I get an Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\InvalidFieldNameException Error (An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO `sys_log` (`userid`, `type`, `channel`, ``...`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [0, 255, "user", "info", 3, 3, 2, "Login-attempt from ###IP### for username '%s' with an empty password!", "a:1:{i:0;s:7:\"username\";}", "", 0, "IP", 1669124385, -1, "", -99]: Unknown column 'channel' in 'field list') - I should do the upgrade scripts, but can't enter the Install Tool...

Comment: Hi alexinge,  I'm getting exactly the same problem "Unknown column 'channel' in 'field list'". Did you come up with a solution to this at all please?

Answer (score 0):

For me it did not work because the, stupid configured docker, project I just started working on was not configured to work with https.
The login to install.php was only possible when I enforced to open the login with https in my browser.